# Snoowrap requester fromAuthCode returns API Error: invalid_grant - undefined

Tags: oauth, reddit

I am able to generate the authorization url, and the code is sucessfully returned to my express endpoint. All this is done in separate methods that I won't bother showing here - simple express routes. They have no affect on the code. I have copy/pasted the auth code from my browser cookies and made a test script that simply calls these functions:

```
const snoowrap = require('snoowrap');
module.exports = {
    getAuthURL: async (managerId, modelId) => {
        return snoowrap.getAuthUrl({
            clientId: process.env.RDT_CLIENT,
            scope: ['privatemessages', 'identity', 'read', 'submit'],
            redirectUri: process.env.REDIRECT_URI,
            permanent: false,
            state: `${managerId}-${modelId}`
        });
    },
    requester: async (token) => {
        let s;
        try {
            s = await snoowrap.fromAuthCode({
                code: token,
                userAgent: process.env.RDT_AGENT,
                clientId: process.env.RDT_CLIENT,
                redirectUri: process.env.REDIRECT_URI,
                clientSecret: process.env.RDT_SECRET,
            });
        } catch (err) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            }
        }
        return s;
    }
}
```

```
require('dotenv').config();
(async () => {
    const requester = await require('./reddit/snoowrap').requester('<CODE GOES HERE>');
    const me = await requester.getMe();
    console.log(me);
})();
```

Calling this function results in this error:
`RequestError: API Error: invalid_grant - undefined`

I have a feeling I am just making a simple mistake here. If anyone with more experience than me could show me the path I would be eternally grateful!

Edit:

Made some progress - I am able to use the grant code a single time, even though I set it to permanent. I think what is happening is when I stop the application, the instance of snoowrap that created the grant code is now destroyed, leaving a useless session cookie behind with it. Can anyone confirm this?

Edit 2:

I made a new access token from authUrl, made a call to snoowrap.me() with that token once, used updateAccessToken() method to update the token and set it to browser cookies, and tried to use the updated token for the next request and it still said invalid_grant on the second function call. Why??